# Calculate End Date Given Start Date & duration (in days)

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, date-arithmetic

I am developing a c#.net solution with a Store Procedure in oracle that calculates End Date based on provided Start date and Duration with weekends.

i.e. Start Date: 01/3/2013 Forward days: 10

Start Date = (05/5/2011) - 10 days (includes weekends)

Start Date = 06/02/2013

thank you,

Comment: search for TimeSpan, DateTime.AddDays

Comment: You missed a complete example. Let's try again: **start** 18-apr-2013, **operation** add, **length** 10. **Result:** 28-apr-2013. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to calculate the end date client-side in C# and pass it to the stored procedure or calculate it server-side in Oracle in the stored procedure; which is it? EDIT: Well, it's ASP.NET so when I say "client-side" I mean in the C# code-behind of the page/control :)

Comment: @ Chris Sinclair - is there a way i can get both. Client and server? Im trying to do it in oracle but want a good way to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a bunch of ways in Oracle. I'd suggest the `INTERVAL` way because it's standard-ish:

```
SELECT yourdate + INTERVAL '10' DAY, ...
```

The single quote around the `10` is required.

The "old" way is to just add 10 to the date; Oracle treats this as days:

```
SELECT yourdate + 10, ...
```

Comment: I have a field for all my start dates for billing and a field for the cycle (days). I am trying to calculate what is end_date based on those two fields.

Comment: I'd go with the "old" way then because the `INTERVAL` really seems to want a constant day value. There may be a way around that but I haven't found it yet. So with the "old" way: `SELECT startdate + cycle, ...` will do the addition properly.

Answer (score 2):

Use of `AddDays` method of `DateTime`

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2013,3,1);
var endDate = startDate.AddDays(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//DateTime start_date = ...
DateTime end_date = start_date.AddDays(10);
```